# Finding location of excecution at any moment

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm currently working on developing a program in Netbeans. Unfortunately, my program tends to freeze a lot, however I'm having trouble figuring out where the issue is. What I would like to do is simply have the debugger highlight the currently executing line inside my code (not inside libraries). Basically stop the code at any point without using a breakpoint. Is there any way to do this in the Netbeans IDE?

Alternately, is there anyway for me to cause a break point to activate (and so show a workable stacktrace) whenever one of my lines of code doesn't move on for a certain period of time?

Profiling does work to some extent, however, it doesn't let me examine variables or get a definitive stack trace.

I am writing this program in Java and I'm using the Java SE version of Netbeans 8.0.2.

Comment: Is your program a java debugger or you are wondering how to debug the program with net beans (sorry, wasn't that clear to me)? [Can't help you much with net beans but eclipse i could].

Comment: @user2494817 I'm using netbeans to debug, though if you have a way to stop the code at any time (not just where there are breakpoints) in eclipse I can use that.

Comment: you would have to build a debug script for it, which is rather tricky. You can google it for more information.

Comment: I recommend using the Java VisualVM profiler/sampler to figure out which functions are using the most CPU. This should give you the best idea of what is using up the most resources. You can find an executable for this inside your JDK's bin folder.

Comment: @Cosmic unfortunately the profiler can sometimes cause performance to suffer where it normally doesn't (at least in my experience). Also, it doesn't tell me precise locations of stops, and it doesn't let me step through code. It's a very helpful tool, but not a substitute for pausing threads.

Comment: I typically use the Sampler instead of the profiler. The sampler will not impact performance, and will give you a statistical summary of which functions are using up the most resources when you click the Snapshot button. The sampler will ask what function is executing now every x milliseconds, instead of reporting every single function call. So, it will give you a very nice overview without causing any performance issues.

Comment: Other than using a sample/profiler, break-points are your best bet (at least in my opinion). As the accepted answer says, you can pause execution in most IDEs, although I've found that that usually that will drop you off in the middle of a random java API function, so not be so useful. For most purposes, you don't need to know what's happening "now," but what's happening most often. Hence a sampler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most IDEs (Eclipse, IntelliJ which I use) have an option to pause all threads in a program.  Look under the debug menus probably in the same place things like step into, step out of etc reside.  A quick Google search on Netbeans IDE says there should be an option under that menu named "pause" that will do what you want.

It will pause all threads of execution in your program.  You will be able to examine the stack of each thread and from there should should be able to figure out where your code is hanging.